# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (n): fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a line (from the data of a second dataframe) to the plot of a first dataframe. Here they are:

```
Year<-c(rep(2001,5),rep(2002,5),rep(2003,5),rep(2004,5),rep(2005,5))
name<-c("John","Ellen","Mark","Randy","Luisa")
Name<-c(rep(name,5))
Value<-sample(seq(0,25,by=1),25)
mydata<-data.frame(Year,Name,Value)

Year_2<-c(2001:2005)
Value_2<-c(1,0,10,3,7)
mydata_2<-data.frame(Year_2,Value_2)
```

This is the plot I want to obtain from the first dataframe:

```
plot<-ggplot(mydata, aes(fill=Name, y=Value, x=Year)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE)+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=11,margin=margin(b=10)),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=11,margin=margin(l=10)),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14,face = "italic"),
        legend.title = element_text(size=18))
```

And I tried to add the line from the second dataframe, in this way:

```
plot +  geom_line(data=mydata_2, size=1, aes(x=Year_2,y=Value_2))
```

Getting this error, which I do not really understand:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): fill
```

I guess it's because `mydata` is of length 25 and `mydata_2` is 5. But what does `fill` has to do with this? Actually, inserting a `fill` argument partially solves the problem:

```
plot +  geom_line(data=mydata_2, size=1, aes(x=Year_2,y=Value_2,fill="red"))
```

Now the plot has the desired line, but I cannot seem to adjust the aesthetic of the line itself (e.g. the colour, that is actually black and not red, or other parameters I tried to add).
Anyway, I tried adjusting the length of `mydata_2`:

```
Year_3<-c(rep(2001,5),rep(2002,5),rep(2003,5),rep(2004,5),rep(2005,5))
Value_3<-c(1,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0)
mydata_3<-data.frame(Year_3,Value_3)
```

Now the line I want is regularly plotted, but with another line following the X-axis. I did not try anything else.

Is there a way to plot `mydata_2` (thus without modifying the length, as in `mydata_3`) and/or to delete the line on the X-axis in `mydata_3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you called `aes()` inside the first `ggplot()`, so it tries to look for `Name`, `Value` and `Year`.

One way to get around is to specify `inherit.aes=FALSE` in second `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(fill=Name, y=Value, x=Year)) +
geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE)+
scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
geom_line(data=mydata_2,inherit.aes=FALSE,aes(x=Year_2,y=Value_2))
```

Or you call `data=` separately in each geom :

```
ggplot() +
geom_bar(data = mydata, aes(fill=Name, y=Value, x=Year),
position="stack", stat="identity") + 
scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE)+
scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
geom_line(data=mydata_2,aes(x=Year_2,y=Value_2))
```

Both of which gives:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about that. Now it's clear (and also works perfectly). Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped 

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = mydata, aes(fill=Name, y=Value, x=Year), position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE)+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=11,margin=margin(b=10)),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=11,margin=margin(l=10)),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14,face = "italic"),
        legend.title = element_text(size=18)) +   
  geom_line(data=mydata_2, aes(x=Year_2,y=Value_2), size=1, color="red")
```